# Android : calling an url while app is on background

Tags: android

I have an app where I detect tags and my question is :
I want my app to do an action when detecting new tags, in this case, opening a webpage. It works without problems but only when the app is on the foreground, but I want it to work even when the app is running in the background. I read about Android Services but I'm not sure it is what I can use.
Can you give me directions to find a way to solve that problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, service is the solution. Rest is a Google or Bing query and reading the tutorials they will list. Another word is "AlarmManager" that will wakeup your Service to poll your URL.

Comment: Best solution is a service...use alarm manager to give intervel of its calling...if you need a sample code i can give...

Answer (score 1):

Please see AsyncTask from google documentation. Here is the link https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

This site has an example on it
http://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/